# VB.net LIST VIEW in need of assistance

Tags: vb.net, listview

[image: this is not my image but similar to what im trying to achieve.]ok, so basically for my college A2 i have been creating a booking system for a tattoo shop, it is to book appointments. i have left the most annoying part(unknowing) till last and time is up

these are my sql tables :

appointment:

| id | tattooId | date | time | length |

tattoo:

| id | customerID | staffID | description |

customer:

| id | name | email| address|

staff:

| id | name| surname| email|

in my forms i have "add appointment" where i pull all the appointments for a selected staff member on a selected date then add a "new appointment" on the date selected, this way i can easily prevent and clashes, and save to the table.

what im now trying to do is create a appointment style view, using a "listview" with the first column representing the time, and the rest are the staff

```
|time| bob | james | billy|
 ---------------------------
|0800|     |       |      |
|0830|frank|       |      |
|0900|     | james |      |
|0930|     |       |      |
|1000|     |       |      |
```

it will look something like this and because when i add appointments i check for clashes i don't need to worry about that now

i just need to pull all the appointments and arrange them in the table somehow

i have a small working version but am stuck if anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

```
    'the columns, tmstr(0) is time column,tmstr(1) is a staff member.
    Dim tmpstr(1) As String
    Dim TempNode As ListViewItem

    ' first column(time column)' 
    For i = 900 To 1700 Step 50
        If i Mod 100 = 50 Then
            tmpstr(0) = i - 20
        Else
            tmpstr(0) = i
        End If

        If i = "1100" Then tmpstr(1) = "appointment, james" Else tmpstr(1) = ""
        TempNode = New ListViewItem(tmpstr)
        ListView1.Items.Add(TempNode)

    Next
```

Comment: do yourself a favor and use a DataGridView instead.  Once you fetch teh data into a DataTable. `myDGV.DataSource = myDataTable` is all you need. The DGV can create columns and add all the rows with zero help from you

Comment: will this work even though i need the appointments to be placed relative to time, because there needs to be blank spaces and only appointments according to the time of the appointment

Comment: ive added a image to my original post, it very similar to what im trying to achieve mine can be allot more basic but the idea is the same :)

Comment: You're using a DataGridView - maybe you need some kind of calendar control instead?

Comment: yea, something like that you may need some sort of calendar control (or rethink the UI).  A LV would still be problematic trying to find appointments in it.